# How to mount a Google cloud disk with Docker-machine / docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

My db uses a spare SSD drive,
I would like to know how I can mount a Google cloud disk with docker-compose and docker-machine.

CoreOS allows to have a mount unit in their cloud-config.yml file :

```
   - name: media-mydisk
      command: start
      content: |
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/disk/by-id/google-mydisk
        Where=/media/mydisk
        Type=btrfs
```

I don't think it should be handled by docker-compose, but docker-machine should be able to do something similar.